# Getting error while trying to add ngrx store after ESLint

Tags: angular, eslint, ngrx

I have an angular 13 application with ESLint already in place.

I have added ngrx store and dev tools using

> ng add @ngrx/store
> ng add @ngrx/store-devtools

commands. now when I try to add store

```
ng g store shared/Shared --module shared.module.ts
```

I get an error

> An unhandled exception occurred: Schematic "store" not found in collection "@angular-eslint/schematics".

.eslintrc file has changes

```
},
{
  "files": [
    "*.ts"
  ],
  "extends": [
    "plugin:ngrx/recommended"
  ]
}
```

and angular.json has this entry

```
  "cli": {
"defaultCollection": "@angular-eslint/schematics"
}
```

how can I retain ESLint and make ngrx work with it ?

Comment: In order to use the schematics tool properly, you should follow the docs: https://ngrx.io/guide/schematics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default collection should be the one from NgRx, or you should execute the schematic by explicitly adding the schematic.

```
  "cli": {
"defaultCollection": "@ngrx/schematics"
}
```

or

```
ng generate @ngrx/schematics:store shared/Shared --module shared.module.ts
```

Comment: No, ESLint will continue to work. the collection has nothing to do with ESLint.

Comment: ok i used the second option but does this means that It wont show ESLint error on thoes files i add with ngrx schematics ?

Comment: ESLint will continue to show warning/errors on all files.